# Issue with Bigquery table created using Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I have created a temporary Bigquery table using Python and loaded data from a panda dataframe (code snippet given below).

`client=bigquery.Client(project)`

`client.create_table(tmp_table)`

`client.load_table_from_dataframe(df,tmp_table)`

The table is being created successfully and I can run select queries from web UI.

But when I run a select query using python

`query =f"""select * from {tmp_table.project_id}.{tmp_table.dataset_id}.{tmp_table.table_id} """`

It throws error *select *  would expand to zero columns*

This is because there python is not able to detect any schema. Below query returns null:

`print(tmp_table.schema)`

If I hardcode the table name like below, it works fine :

`query =f"""select * from project_id.dataset_id.table_id """`

Can someone suggest how do I get data from the temporary table using a select query in python? I can't hardcode table name as it's being created at runtime.

Comment: are you able to verify the text of your failed query by looking up failed query jobs in the UI? Is it the same as the hard-coded query text?

Comment: @rjh336 yeah, it's the same.

Comment: Hey @kritika-pandey did you ever come to a solution here? If no, are you able to post the query text, job results, and execution results of the pandas initiated query and the hardcoded query from the UI?